# Material design in ionicframework:Module ionic-material is not avaliable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-material

I using [ionic+material](http://ionicmaterial.com/) to setup material design in ionic framework.
I just run the demo app that in the code samples,but i will get this error

> module 'ionic-material' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ionic-material','ionMdInput'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ion-md-input/css/ion-md-input.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic-material/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-material/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ion-md-input/js/ion-md-input.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development)-->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can You show me your html page?

Comment: Can you check on browser console window every js files and css files loaded successfully?

Comment: Everything is loaded correctly

Comment: What version of ionic do you have installed? of Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

Change the reference  of `ionic.material.min.js` in the  sample, with the one in this [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.js)

This will work in *Firefox*, for *Chrome* use a downloaded file of the same

Answer (score 0):

You must remove ionic-material in

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','ionic-material','ionMdInput'])
```

you need change ionicMaterialInk to ionic.material.ink
and ionicMaterialMotion. to ionic.material.motion